# Stability of CsQuery 1.3.5-beta5?

Tags: csquery

Can anyone comment from experience on the stability of CsQuery 1.3.5-beta5? (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/1.3.5-beta5).

I am about to spike CsQuery and notice that 1.3.5 includes "significant performance improvements and bug fixes". Of course I haven't forgotten it's a beta which is why I ask if anyone has any experience to share?

(Running on Windows Server 2012, as part of a windows service)

Comment: And why hasn't it been approved as a stable release yet?